# Illogical type Inference in Java8

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I would like to know why the code `☆2` can be compiled with `Java8`:

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ☆1: NG: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
        String res0 = IList.nil().head(); 

        // ☆2: OK: I don't know why it's OK.
        String res1 = IList.nil().head2();
    }

    static class IList<E> {

        static <Z> IList<Z> nil() {
            return null;
        }

        E head() {
            return null;
        }

        <TeE extends E> TeE head2() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: 
Also I am wondering that the JEP(http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)'s goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java typically defaults generics to their outer bound.  In this particular case it types as

```
 String res1 = IList.<Object>nil().<String>head2();
```

...because only the outermost method call "knows" the desired result type.

Comment: Is this a Java 8 change?

Comment: You should probably put a note to that effect in response to `I would like to know why the code ☆2 can be compiled with Java8:`

Comment: Java 8 does feature more powerful type interference. So compile-time behaviour from Java 7 to Java 8, *without Type witnesses*, may differ.

Comment: I believe this particular case should be the same in both Java 8 and Java 7.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Indeed correct, there's no change between Java 8 and Java 7 here. It's two different methods so there's no reason why it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @skiwi, not only does Java 8 feature more powerful type interference, it also features more powerful type inference. :-)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you have some concretely example for the JEP(http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)’s goal `Add support for method type-parameter inference in chained calls`?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Java 8. #2 also compiles on Java 7.

I think what it all boils down to is `<TeE extends E>` in your `head2` method. Java sees that you're expecting a `String` in return, because of this line:

```
String res1 = IList.nil().head2();
```

Therefore it concludes that, ah, in that case I'll return a `String` for now - because `String` extends `Object`, so the `<TeE extends E>` is valid.

This works thanks to the fact you're returning null inside the method. If you would not do that, an error would occur within that method. And as null can be assigned to everything but primitives, this code is OK.